# Magento 2.3 : Category attribute disabled when changing the store?

Tags: magento2.3, category-attribute, wysiwyg

In Magento 2.3 we have few custom attribute and one of which is **Wyswyg** type and that went disabled **i.e., can't editable** when switching store.

> NOTE : when changing the use default option from content->description is un-checked it can be editable.

[image]

It was working fine in M2.2.7.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Thanks

Comment: is attribute set as global?

Comment: No, the scope in store level

Comment: how about try changing to golbal scope and check if it works even chaning stores

Comment: try changing the scope of the attribute to global